# Riemannian metrics on 2-sphere invariant under antipodal involution

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

EDIT: Let $g$ be a smooth Riemannian metric on $S^2$ which is invariant under the antipodal involution $x\mapsto -x$. Assume it has Gauss curvature at least $-1$ and diameter $D$.

> Does there exist a constant $c(D)>0$ (but independent of the metric) such that $\sup_x dist(x,-x)\geq c(D)$?

Comment: @alesia : Thanks, corrected.  It remained from an earlier version of the question I wanted to ask.

Comment: MKO: since you accepted Anton's answer I assume you understand it. Could you explain why the diameter of $\Delta$ is at least $D$?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: I gave more details in my answer below. Actually, as pointed out below, the esimate of diameter of $\Delta$ is $D/2$. But may be after Anton corrected his answer my remarks are not necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is "yes".

Let $g$ be the induced Riemannian metric on $\mathbb R\mathrm P^2=\mathbb S^2/\mathbb Z_2$.
Denote by $\ell$ the systole of $(\mathbb R\mathrm P^2,g)$ and let $\gamma$ be the corresponding closed geodesic.
Let us cut $(\mathbb R\mathrm P^2,g)$ along $\gamma$. 
We obtain a disc $\Delta$ with diameter is at least $D/2$ and its boundary has length $2\cdot\ell$.

Note that we can assume that $\ell<D/100$.
Therefore there is a point $x$ in $\Delta$ that lies on distance at least $D/10$ from the boundary.
It remains to note that the distance from $x$ to its antipodal point is more than $D/10$.

Comment: Why is the diameter of $\Delta$ at least $D$?

Comment: it should be at least $D/2$ for sure

Comment: @IgorBelegradek fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer. Following the request of Igor Belegradek I would like to elaborate on Anton Petrunin's answer and prove that $diam (\Delta) \geq D/2$.

First of all $diam (\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2)\geq D/2$. This is a special case of the more general estimate proved in the final answer to this post:   [Diameter of m-fold cover](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7732/diameter-of-m-fold-cover/7880#7880)

Let $f\colon S^2\to \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ be the canonical map. Let $a\colon S^2\to S^2$ be the antipodal involution. Then $\tilde\gamma:=f^{-1}(\gamma)$ is a closed connected (!) geodesic on $S^2$, it is $a$-invariant. By the Jordan theorem its complement consists of two disks whose closures will be denoted by $\Delta $ and $\Delta'$. (Say, the first disk is the one Anton constructed, I guess.) Then
$$a(\Delta)=\Delta'.(1)$$
Indeed otherwise $a(\Delta)=\Delta$. In that case the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ would act freely on the disk $\Delta$ which is imposible since in that case the quotient $\Delta/\mathbb{Z}_2$ would be a compact manifold (possibly with boundary) of Euler characteristic 1/2 which is absurd.

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ be such that $dist(x,y)\geq D/2$. Let $\tilde x,\tilde y \in \Delta$ be their lifts (they can be chosen to belong to $\Delta$ due to (1)).
Then one has
$$diam(\Delta)\geq dist(\tilde x,\tilde y)\geq \min\{dist(\tilde x,\tilde y),dist (\tilde x,a(\tilde y))\}=dist(x,y)\geq D/2.$$
QED