# German mathematical terms like "Nullstellensatz"

Tags: terminology, big-list

There are quite a few german mathematical theorems or notions which usually are not translated into other languages. For example,

[Nullstellensatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullstellensatz), [Hauptvermutung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptvermutung), [Freiheitssatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiheitssatz), [Eigenvector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvector) (the "Eigen" part), [Verschiebung](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0804/0804.3888.pdf).

For me, as a German, this is quite entertaining. Do you know other examples? Please one per answer, please give a reference for the term or a short explanation of what it means.

It would be great to see an explanation why there is no translation.

EDIT: Some more examples can be found at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_expressions_in_English#Mathematics_and_formal_logic): Ansatz, Entscheidungsproblem, Grossencharakter, Hauptmodul, Möbius band, quadratfrei, Stützgerade, Vierergruppe, Nebentype.

Comment: Does Eigenvalue count as an answer...?

Comment: Hauptidealsatz (sometimes)


Comment: The notation $\mathbb Z$ comes from "Zahlen".

Comment: Regarding the 'explanation' part: do you mean a general one for the phenomenon, or one for each individual word. One ther question: you say 'other languages', but for example I doubt 'Eigen' is used in French. Perhaps, to limit to English could focus the discussion. 

Comment: Grossencharacter (not quite German spelling, but close).

Comment: Stufe (of a field).

Comment: *Grössencharakter* is used by Helmut Koch, 
Kiyosi Ito, Borel-Casselman,

Comment: @KConrad: Please post this as an answer :)

Comment: The symbol $K$ that we use for fields most of time comes from the German word for field "Körper".

Comment: By the way, there are also non-mathematical words in English that are simply taken over from German, e.g. kindergarten, gesundheit, doppelgänger, ...

Comment: @unknown: indeed, the French term for eigenvector is "vecteur propre".

Comment: "Möbius band" isn't really German. "Möbius" is a name and "band" is a perfectly reasonable German word. Oddly enough, the space seems to make the difference here; "Möbiusband" would feel much more German to me. I'm a native speaker of English; I have a mere smattering of German, enough to find the German Wikipedia article for this object and see what it's called in German.

Comment: @Micheal Lugo: I assume the second German should be English. That is, "band" is a perfectly reasonable English word. 

Comment: We also have quite a few French terms as well.  Just a few examples:  "surejective" ('sur' means 'on', therefore 'onto'), "injective" ('un' means one, therefore 'one to one').

Comment: If chess is mathematics... I know 3 German words used among english speaking chess players: zugzwang, zwichenzug and zeitnot. There's also the french en passant.

Comment: thats zwischenzug.. it's really bad that you can't edit comments in MO

Comment: @unknown (google): you're right, the second "German" in my comment should be "English". My point is that "Möbius band" feels English to me and "Möbiusband" feels German.

Comment: And for those who want to know the German spelling: "Größencharakter".

Comment: Certainly I've seen _square-free_ or _squarefree_ more often than _quadratfrei_.

Comment: *Festschrift* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festschrift) is often used in academia.

Comment: As for "band" being a "reasonable German word", it would appear (see dict.leo.org) that there are three word with three different genders:
"das Band" = belt (that you wear); "der Band" = volume (of a journal or an encyclopedia or the like; "die Band" = ensemble of musicians, and I think in this last case they may pronounce the vowel as in English.  So it seems it would be a neuter noun if it refers to the topological space named after Möbius, although I don't know what Germans call that.

Comment: @Michael Hardy, yes in German it is 'das Möbiusband'; perhaps to clarify the belt translation, let me add that 'das Band' often also means 'tape', for example 'das Klebeband' is adhesive tape, or 'das Tonband' is audio tape, and the belt one should think of as a translation of 'das Band' is not a leather belt with a buckle (this would be 'der Gürtel'), but more, something like, a tape of velvet. 

Comment: I collect these german names too. Many have been posted already, and my favorite one is a physics term so I post it here in the comments: [Bremsstrahlung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung).

Comment: Two answers today, both duplicates. Time to close, I think.

Comment: With no doubt I think that german is the language for maths.

Comment: In physics, I remember having studied "inverse Brehmstrahlung" and "Aufbauprinzip". I consider calling an element of a field generated by L-functions not being an L-function itself an (L-)Geist, as talking about "fantômes" in French in maths wouldn't sound quite serious.

Comment: In the symbol for cusp forms $S_k(\Gamma)$, $S$ stands for *Spitze*.

Comment: For an extension of number fields, I've already seen the ramification, inertia and decomposition subgroups denoted $V_j \leq T \leq Z$ respectively, because of _Verzweigung, Trägkeit, Zerlegung_.

Comment: Also in chess, before the adoption of clocks: Sitzfleisch (the ability to sit there for hour after hour); this could be applied to mathematics, I suppose.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Führerdiskriminantenproduktformel.

Comment: I had to google this to convince myself it was not a joke...

Comment: What does that translate to anyway?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor-discriminant_formula

Comment: Dear Chandan, This is the example that came to my mind when I read the question too.  (It's strange to read that this seems funny to non-algebraic number theorists ... .)  Best wishes, Matt

Comment: Can't resist to post this drawing by Mark Twain who was a special friend of the german language which is famous for its long words...http://www.gutenberg.org/files/5788/5788-h/5788-h.htm#p612

Comment: Now I can't resist: 'Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftsraddampferkapitänskajütentürersatzsicherheitsschlüsselhaken'

The above is artificial but apparently this:
'Rinderkennzeichnungs-_und_rindfleischetikettierungsuberwachungsaufgabenubertragungsgesetz' was the name of an actual draft for a bill.

On a more serious note, the feature (or bug) of the German language of allowing more or less arbitrary concatenations of nouns to create new words seems to be one of the reasons why some expressions remain untransated/untranslateable.

[If this is too off-topic let me now and I delete.]

Comment: Dear unknown, concatenation is non-assocative. Proof: Mädchen(handelsschule) $\neq$ (Mädchenhandels)schule

Comment: Dear Georges Elencwajg, yes, and even if the decomposition is actually unique one can cause confusion. Some people like to tease kids by pronouncing the following wrong and asking them whether they know what it means: Blumento|pferde (suggesting Blumento-horses which do not exist) instead of Blumentopf|erde (flower-pot soil); same for Palat|schinken (suggesting it is Palat-ham which does not exist) which is actually just one word Palatschinken (some form of crepe, derived from Czech, Hungarian, or Romanian).

Answer (score 75):

The notation  $G_\delta$ is from German, $G$ for *Gebiet*, and $\delta$ for *Durchschnitt*. Strangely enough, the notation for the co-sets, $F_\sigma$, is from French, *fermé* and *somme*.

Comment: I did not know that, it's very cool! Well, I suspected that the F stood for "fermé", but then you tend to automatically assume that G was used because it's the next letter available... So far, this has to be my favorite answer.

Comment: I always thought this was the origin of $F_\sigma$, but it looks like the notation originated with Hausdorff and there's no evidence he had anything French in mind (although I guess there's no proof he didn't).  See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74004/what-does-the-in-algebra-stand-for.

Comment: Are you sure $\sigma$ is for French *somme* and not German *Summe*?

Comment: Yes, $\sigma$ may come from any language where the term for “sum” comes from Latin; but I think $F$ for “closed” can only be from French. I learnt the information about $G_\delta$ and $F_\sigma$ from the book “Real Analysis” by E.Stein and Rami Shakarchi (footnote on page 23).

Answer (score 55):

[Ansatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz). Although I suppose it is used more in physics than in mathematics. I don't know why the translation is not used often, but I guess it has to do something with the fact that in the beginning of the 20th century German was used much more than English in the scientific literature, I believe.

Comment: Which translation?

Comment: Well maybe not a literal translation, but in most cases "educated guess" can be used as well.

Comment: @Pieter: Maybe that this is really the closest english expression, but personally I would never use it, because an "Ansatz" has a very different feeling than a "Schuss ins Blaue" / "educated guess". If you have an Ansatz, you have an idea of what is going on or should be going on. Maybe you have physical reasons to believe that the solution of your equation should have a particular nice form or something like that. An educated guess on the other hand is ... well, guessing. And that is a very different kind of approach I think.

Comment: @Johannes Hahn, while I tend to agree that 'Ansatz' is not really an 'educated guess' I would say 'Schuss ins Blaue' is neither; as this I believe is more a 'shot in the dark' so a 'wild guess'. 

Comment: @Johannes Hahn: I would say an educated guess is more than guessing. In fact, what you describe would qualify as an educated guess in my book. I agree though that "Ansatz" is a bit stronger, which probably is one of the reasons that it is widely used. I am not a native speaker of English (nor German), so perhaps my notion of an educated guess is off.

Comment: I would put Ansatz closer to Postulate than to Educated Guess: you make an educated guess as to what is going on, but then you stick with that to all its consequences and only afterwards see if you got it right or not, and what kind of solid (a posteriori) evidence you can collect.

Comment: As @EmilioPisanty points out, I thought that an Ansatz was something more than an educated guess; I had always assumed, though, that it was less rigorous than a postulate—more a heuristic.

Comment: Two other English terms which get close to the meaning of "Ansatz", without quite hitting the mark, are "template" and "attempt". One has to interpolate somewhere in between these terms, and others mentioned above.

Comment: The German word is probably used because there is not a word in English which is an exact translation.  In some languages like Spanish, German words do not seem to be used as much in mathematics, so eigenvectors are called vectores propios, but they still use the word Ansatz instead of estimación or a similar word.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt Template makes no sense in this context, but ''attempt at a solution'' is probably fine.

Comment: @HollisWilliams - I don't understand your comment at all. With an ansatz, you posit a certain pattern for a solution, in which variable elements, such as coefficients, correction terms, etc. are still adjustable. That matches the meaning of "template" very well. Better actually than the various shades of guessing that have been proposed.

Answer (score 40):

This is an answer to the part of the question about why these terms are not translated into English. The reason is that  words such as "nullstellensatz",  "Schadenfreude" and so on that you mistakenly think are German are in fact perfectly good English words and so do not need translation. (Look up  [Schadenfreude in the Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/172271?rskey=ZZodoS&result=8&isAdvanced=false#) if you do not believe it is an English word, though they have not yet caught up with nullstellensatz.) The point is that unlike languages such as French and German that try to remain pure, English has been happily looting terms  from other languages for centuries, and the only difference between "nullstellensatz" and "house" is that "house" was stolen so long ago that we have forgotten about it.

Comment: *English has been happily looting...*  For example the word *loot* (लूट) from us Indians.

Comment: Whether this is done more 'happily' in English, I don't know. But, it is certainly also done in German, with certain regional variations in the extent (three of the italic words might not be common everywhere, but the others are universal several even without common alternative): "Von der *Trafik* aus, *flanierte* ich ueber das *Trottoir*, einen *salutierenden* *Offizier* mit *Pistole* und einen *Portier* *nonchalant* *passierend*, ins *Souterrain*." And, in France you might well wish your collegues after a 'planning' on friday afternooon 'bonne week-end'.

Comment: Richard does have a point in that, if you count *all* the words that have been imported into English, the total dwarfs the word total of similar languages, like French. Of course, whether it truly measures the richness of the language is a different question, but there is no denying that English is *especially* eager to accommodate new words. Probably, part of the answer lies with the almost total lack of any morphological constraints on the words.

Comment: @Chandan: one can imagine Indians using that word a lot in talking with/about the Englsh, initially :)

Comment: Thierry Zell, granted on a historical scale this should be true. 
What I mainly wanted to point out is that import of foreign words, at some point mainly French and more recently mainly English, into German is all but exceptional. And, thus I think it would be a misunderstanding of the original question (not sure if this happended) to believe that its cause is likely that there are no/few words of English origin in frequent use in German. But rather the converse, i.e., that in view of the large import of E. into G. also (surprisingly) some export happens.

Comment: Sorry, but "house" most certainly did not come into English from German. The word hus occurs in every one of the oldest Germanic languages. By standard sound-changes, the long "u" shifted to "ou" in English, just as "ut" became "out", "mus" became "mouse", etc.

Comment: Indeed.  Words like house were not 'looted' from German, but have been part of English (in some form) for as long as such a language has existed.  So such words did come into English from German, but only in the sense that the whole language (until 'recent' borrowings) did.


Comment: Bof -- the French loot as many words as anglophones, they just frenchify them quickly.  My favourite current regular -er verb is "liker", snaffled from facebook: je like, tu likes, il like, nous likons, ...

Comment: This is a rather weak argument. Both “Nullstellensatz” and “Schadenfreude” are compound nouns whose individual parts are German but not English words (except for possibly “Null”, which however means “zero” here).

Answer (score 34):

All this should be compiled in a *Festschrift*.

Answer (score 31):

This is a notation rather than a term, but the wide use of the letter $K$ to denote a field in Algebra refers to the German word *Körper*.

Comment: And $\mathfrak O$ comes from *Ordnung*.

Comment: While the customary $U$ for subspaces comes from _Unterraum_.

Comment: And the $U$ for a neighbourhood comes from *Umgebung*.

Comment: Surfaces are denoted $F$ in some of Mumford's books because of the German word *Fläche*.

Comment: In older books on representation theory, representations are usually denoted $D$, from *Darstellung*.


Comment: I always assumed $U$ was for subspaces because you call a topological space $T$ for topological space, and when you take a subspace of it, you just take the next letter.

Comment: The Z for the center of a group/algebra/etc comes from Zentrum

Comment: @BinGui, although some people have the to-me baffling convention of using $Z_\cdot(\cdot)$ for centraliser and $C(\cdot)$ for centre (so that $Z_G(C(G)) = G$), whereas I would use the opposite convention ($\mathrm Z(\cdot)$ for centre and $\mathrm C_\cdot(\cdot)$ for centraliser, so that $\mathrm C_G(\mathrm Z(G)) = G$).

Answer (score 30):

Jugendtraum (Kronecker).

Comment: Was it Avner Ash who said "I'm too old to have a Jugendtraum"?

Comment: @Laurent: Certainly not Manin.  See his 
*Real multiplication and noncommutative geometry 
(ein Alterstraum)* in 
The legacy of Niels Henrik Abel, 
Springer, Berlin, 2004. 

Comment: *Last but not least, I appreciate the proposal of Friedrich Hirzebruch to translate Alterstraum in the title as "midlife crisis".*  ---Manin
$$ $$

Answer (score 23):

The word *idele* ultimately comes from the abbreviation
"id. ele." for *ideales Element*.

Comment: The word idele often is written with an accent on the first e, hinting at its French origin (Chevalley introduced ideal elements, and Hasse suggested the word idel; see p. 91 in Emil Artin und Helmut Hasse: die Korrespondenz 1923 - 1934, available online).

Comment: It is true that the word *idèle* was introduced by Chevalley but it was based on the German contraction "id. ele." for *ideales Element*.  If it has been based on a French contraction, it would have been *éléïde*.

Comment: ...unless it's _verlan_! [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan].

Comment: Non, non, c'est pas du verlan.  L’étymologie du mot d’« idèle » est bien documentée.

Answer (score 22):

An indirect answer:

Klein bottle

which has probably started out as:

Kleinsche Fläche (=Klein surface)

Kleinsche Flache (lost umlaut in English print)

Klein bottle (translation of Flasche instead of Flache)

Comment: In German I never heard this called anything else than 'Kleinsche Flasche' (I thus somewhat doubt there was the development you sketch). 

Comment: It was then retranslated to German as Kleinsche Flasche which I omitted above because the question asks about usage in English.

So unless you are 120 years old, you have no chance to have heard Kleinsche Fläche.

Comment: Here the commenting unknown again: sorry for my initial doubts. What you write certainly agrees with the German Wikipedia entry, though that entry is a bit vague (as it is more or less reportes a rumour).
Perhaps I will try to find some more information. If this turns out to be true it is a quite fun development. 

So, +1.
  

Comment: After a bit of googling, I found the term "Kleinsche Fläche in an old German book:

http://books.google.com/books?id=N87UIpgFp5oC&pg=PA275&lpg=PA275&dq=kleinsche+fl%C3%A4che&source=bl&ots=ksTGJqwu_p&sig=gh7Lq7LpVmqxaMThfqpjiwoqLWc&hl=de&ei=k3WtTayeBMvEsgav_5nXDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=kleinsche%20fl%C3%A4che&f=false

Comment: It will certainly be hard or impossible to prove the last step in the development as one would have to verify that bottle turns up first in English.
But it is certainly true that it started out as Fläche/Flache.

On the other hand, it could be easily disproved by a letter from a mathematician stating his motivations to introduce the name bottle. 

Comment: @Tara Brough, thank you. @unknown (the answering one): yes, I didn't doubt so much that it started as 'Fläche' (I should have phrased my initially comment more carefully). But how could possibly a translation occur that changes 'Fläche', or 'Flache' or even 'Flaeche' into 'bottle' by mistaking it for 'Flasche' in a *math context* ?! If it were called 'Klein flat' (flach=flat, adj.), then fine, I would believe any time in a transl. problem. But 'bottle' as a *result of translation* (rather than a decision, as a play on the shape, in whichever language), this is really hard to believe.   

Comment: Some more information: Wiki-page (engl.) references 'Low-dimensional geometry: from Euclidean surfaces to hyperbolic knots' by Bonahon for the name. This book (p.95) however does *not* refer this as fact but rather says (emphasize mine): 'The "bottle" terminology is usually understood to reflect the fact that a Klein bottle can be obtained from a regular wine bottle by [...]. Another interpretation (*unverified*, and not incompatible with the previous one) claims that it comes from a *bad pun*, or a bad translation from the German [...]' 
 

Comment: Very interesting! I wonder which came first---the term "Klein bottle," or the standard bottle-shaped immersion of the Klein bottle? To me, the picture of the Klein surface in the book Tara Brough linked is quite striking---I don't think I've ever seen the Klein surface drawn that way, even though it's a perfectly natural way of doing it.

Comment: There is in German a term "Kleinsche Fläche", which refers to very particular Riemann surfaces. See for example [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01226089). I once listened to a talk where the speaker emphasized that "Kleinsche Fläche" and "Kleinsche Flasche" are completely different things ...

Answer (score 20):

Verlagerung.  Sometimes translated as the *transfer*.

Comment: In *Corps locaux*, Serre uses $\mathrm{Ver}$ for the transfer map, noting that it is "called transfer (*Verlagerung* in German)."

Answer (score 19):

Nebentypus, Positivstellensatz.

Answer (score 18):

Apparently the term K-theory comes from the German word "Klasse", according to Wikipedia and  http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602082

Comment: You're probably right, but the truth should never interfere with 
a good story. What I heard is that the (contravariant
functor) K comes from grothendiecK. There is also a covariant G.

Comment: @Donu: I've never heard that one, but I like it. At least it's a good mnemonic.

Comment: That the *K* of K-theory comes from *Klasse* is explained by Grothendieck himself in the first issue of the journal *K-theory*. He first wanted to use *C*, from the French word "classe", but being an analyst he feared that it would cause a confusion with $C(X)$, the continuous functions on $X$. So he decided to use the initial of  the translation of "classe" in his native German, Klasse.

Comment: Georges, OK, you have me convinced. But the alternate explanation,
that I think I learned from Grayson, had sounded preposterous enough
to be true.

Answer (score 18):

Umkehr map (pushforward map).

Comment: The term "Umkehrabbildung" (Abbildung being the german word for map) usually refers to and is translated as "inverse map". Do you know why are pushforwards are named like this? I mean $f_\ast$ is usually not invers to $f$ or even to $f^\ast$...

Comment: @Johannes: Usually you use the term Umkehr map when a map going in the other direction is much easier to define, hence the “reversal”.

Comment: Strangely enough, many topologists in Germany tend to call umkehr maps "pushforward". Maybe because otherwise they could be confused with inverse maps; maybe "pushforward" just sounds more faashionable.

Answer (score 16):

Here's another one: [Hauptvermutung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptvermutung)

Comment: I already mentioned this in (the first version of my) question. But don't mind :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry -- I looked for it, but didn't see it.

Answer (score 14):

In GR (and other branches of mathematical physics) one uses *vierbein* (tetrad) and more often these days also *vielbein*, for local orthonormal frames in a (pseudo-)riemannian manifold.

Answer (score 14):

Plastikstufe = a certain higher dimensional analogue of an overtwisted disk in contact geometry.  This is not a real German word.  It is a compound of the German words for "plastic" and "step", but this does not have any obvious relevance to its mathematical meaning.  There is a funny story about where this word came from which however is not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: How can it be non appropriate to this forum if it is the origin of a mathematical term, in the context of a discussion of mathematical terms?!

Comment: I remember having heard the story a few years back :D Plastikstufe is a real german word, though: In german words can be composed like this. A Plastikstufe is a step (in a stair) made out of plastic.

Answer (score 13):

The *Verschiebung* morphism.

Answer (score 13):

Größencharakter.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hecke_character

Answer (score 12):

Gentzen's Hauptsatz (cut elimination theorem) : This is a fundamental result in structural proof theory, and is at the heart of Gentzen's consistency proof of elementary number theory.  It is very funny that the word literally means "main theorem," with no reference to the subject domain, yet it is standard in logic in English to use just the word "Hauptsatz" to refer to this (family of) theorem(s) in proof theory.

Answer (score 12):

Zugzwang - a sort of Nash Equilibrium. This terminology is specifically used in Chess.

Comment: I'm familiar with the chess term, but didn't know it had been used formally in game theory. Is the definition exactly as in chess?

Comment: @Yemon: apparently yes. From wikipedia: "The term finds its formal definition in combinatorial game theory, and it describes a situation where one player is put at a disadvantage because he has to make a move when he would prefer to pass and make no move."

Answer (score 11):

I've seen *schlicht-function* for functions $f(x)=x +a x^2 + b x^3 + \cdots$ for powerseries without constant term and $f'(0)=1 $. But I do not really know, whether this is really the german word *schlicht* (=*simple*) or only some coincidence.

Comment: It certainly is the german word *schlicht* (maybe innocuous would be a more adequate translation than simple). Conformal mapping was dominated by the German school (Koebe, Bieberbach) before the Finnish school took over. However, *univalent* seems to be the preferred term nowadays.

Comment: In complex function theory, "schlicht" is usually a synonym for one-to-one.

Comment: Could you tell me what is meant by "schlicht annular region" or by "schlicht domain"?



Answer (score 11):

Die Vierergruppe.

Comment: I've also heard it called "The Group of Fear".

Answer (score 11):

deck transformation?

Comment: Isn't that just good ol' boring English? (It was probably Germanic a few hundred years ago, of course :) )

Comment: @Mariano: Is it? I thought the "deck" in "deck transformation" comes from "Überdeckung" (=covering).

Comment: @JHahn: well, "deck" is an English word, isn't it?

Comment: I had thought the name "deck transformation" was thought of like shuffling a "deck" of cards.   I'm not a native speaker either, so is this too far fetched?

Comment: @KlausNiederkrüger it is good mnemonic rule, but historically (IMHO) it comes from German.

Answer (score 10):

"Urelement" is used in set theory as a fancy name for an atom, i.e., something that can be a member of a set but is not itself a set.

Comment: Ur- as a prefix is frequently used in ordinary English, though; see sense 3 at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ur .

Answer (score 10):

Some famous book published in about 1950 says that for lack of an English word for the concept the word *Faltung* is used.  In recent decades, the adapted Latin word *convolution* has served.

Paul Halmos tried unsuccessfully to expunge the words *eigenvector* and *eigenvalue* from the language, using the terms *proper vector* and *proper value* in his book *Finite-dimensional Vector Spaces*.

Answer (score 9):

**Stufe** (=level) of a non-real field ([wikipedia.de](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stufe_(Algebra))). It is the least number of squares $a_i^2$ such that $\sum_i a_i^2 = -1$, $\infty$ if no such sum exists.

In [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02785578), the *level* of a subgroup of $SL_2(\mathcal{O})$ is defined ($\mathcal{O}$ a number field), as the generalisation of the stufe of a field, so the term has been translated, but only in a shift of context.

To pick a random paper, try [The stufe of number fields](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01142578).

Comment: Whoops, I saw KConrad got this one in the comments, and Martin wanted him to post it as an answer.

Comment: Allow me to add the following quote from Gödel's 1940 book about the relative consistency of GCH and AC with ZF: _The latter proof requires the singling out of one element in every non empty class, which however can be accomplished by considering, in every class, the sub**set** of elements of lowest "Stufe" (in the sense of J. v. Neumann [...])_. Here "Stufe" = rank, in the sense of the cumulative hierarchy.

Answer (score 8):

There's Soergel's [Endomorphismensatz](http://books.google.com/books?id=8GCP4Ng6risC&lpg=PA266&ots=oIeehaWMSs&dq=Endomorphismensatz&pg=PA266#v=onepage&q=Endomorphismensatz&f=false) and [Struktursatz](http://books.google.com/books?id=dtsUcQTHPqYC&lpg=PA120&ots=xa33PP-eAi&dq=struktursatz%20Soergel&pg=PA120#v=onepage&q=struktursatz%20Soergel&f=false).

Answer (score 6):

Verschränkungsoperator is the (perhaps even original) german version of "intertwiner" which I really like. But I've not seen that very much ;)

Answer (score 6):

Viergeflechte, the original German name for 2-bridge knots, still occasionally used in an English context. In his Mathematical Review of Schubert's 1956 paper "Knoten mit 2 Bruecken" Fox explicitly notes that "Viergeflecht" is untranslatable.

Answer (score 5):

Zahlbericht (Hilbert), Klassenkörperbericht (Hasse),
Das blaue Hasse (Zahlentheorie, Akademie-Verlag, Berlin).

Answer (score 5):

The practice to use Gothic letters sometimes for ideals ($\mathfrak{a}$, $\mathfrak{b}$, ...) and often for Lie algebras ($\mathfrak{g}$, $\mathfrak{h}$, ..) seems to be of German origin.

Also to use the lesser known "kernel" instead of the better known "core" seems to stem from the German "Kern".

Comment: "Kernel" and "nucleus" seem to me to be the most obvious options for English translation of German "Kern", although "core" would have been possible.

Comment: The choice of "core" for Kern would have led to "cocore" for Cokern.

Comment: I don't know what to think about the gothic letters: yes, it is German in origin because it was the alphabet used in German back then. But borrowing symbols wouldn't rank it the same way as borrowing a word, I think.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to mention a handful of examples that may be considered *passé* nowadays, but were prominent at some point in time.

- **Schlicht**: I dare to address this once again because I consider that the feedback in the comments below Gottfried's entry is kind of misleading. About this one, Boas says that (see [**1**, page 97]):

> ... When I was an undergraduate, there was no regular colloquium at
>   Harvard, but there was a Mathematical Club, whose meetings were
>   regularly attended by faculty. Once somebody gave a talk on schlicht
>   functions. After the talk, Julian Lowell Coolidge asked plaintively
>   whether there was an English word for 'schlicht'. Osgood replied,
>   "Well, you *could* call them univalent functions, and everybody would
>   know that you meant 'schlicht'". You need to know that Osgood had been
>   trained in Germany, wrote his treatise on complex analysis in German,
>   and was apt to tell German jokes to his classes.

It has to be noted that in practice *univalent* and *schlicht* are not perfect synonyms. For instance, on *Function theory of one complex variable* by Greene and Krantz, we can read this (my emphasis):

> A holomorphic function $f$ **on the unit disc** $D$ is usually called
>   *schlicht* if $f$ is one-to-one. We are interested in such one-to-one $f$ that satisfy the normalizations $f(0)=0$ and $f^{\prime}(0)=1.$ In
>   what follows, we restrict the word *schlicht* to mean one-to-one with
>   these normalizations.

What is more, several online sources include right from the start those normalizations in their definition of *schlicht*, e.g., [planetmath.org](http://planetmath.org/schlichtfunctions), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Branges%27s_theorem), and [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchlichtFunction.html).

- **Aussonderungsaxiom**: Of all axioms of Zermelo, I have noticed that, for some godforsaken reason, in some books/papers written in English (and even in Spanish) this one is (or was) occasionally called by its German name.
- **Limes:** That's right... It was not a typo in Ahlfors's text on Complex Analysis. I recently came across this one in another book, but I just can't recall which one it was.

EDIT: According to Gerald Edgar "limes" is a Latin word. Yet, I will leave it here because I believe that it is a loan word in German which made it to other languages due to the influence of treatises written originally in German.

- **Drehstreckung:** Tristan Needham recalls this one when he apologizes for the coinage of the term 'amplitwist'. More specifically, he writes

> To the expert reader I would like to apologize for having invented the
>   word 'amplitwist' ... as a synonym (more or less) for 'derivative', as
>   well the component terms 'amplification' and 'twist'. I can only say
>   that the need for *some* such terminology was forced on me in the
>   classroom: if you try teaching the ideas in this book *without* using
>   such language, I think you will quickly discover what I mean!
>   Incidentally, a precedence argument in defence (sic) of 'amplitwist'
>   might be that a similar term was coined by the older German school of
>   Klein, Bieberbach, *et al*. They spoke of 'eine Drehstreckung', from
>   'drehen' (to twist) and 'strecken' (to stretch).

Last but not least, in several works of old (z.B., Perron's *Die Lehre von den Kettenbrüchen*, Knopp's *Theory and Application of Infinite series*, Khinchin's *Continued Fractions*), there appears the following notation for general continued fractions:

$$\underset{j=1}{\overset{\infty}{\LARGE\mathrm K}}\frac{a_j}{b_j} = \cfrac{a_1}{b_1+\cfrac{a_2}{b_2+\cfrac{a_3}{b_3+\ddots}}}.$$

Guess what the $\mathrm{K}$ stands for...

**References**

[**1**] Lion Hunting & Other Mathematical Pursuits: A Collection of Mathematics, Verse and Stories by Ralph P. Boas Jr.

Comment: Do you happen to know the meaning of the term "schicht domain" or "schicht region"? I have seen this in a paper of Huber published in the 50s and I am still unsure what it means.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. Anyway, thanks a lot for taking a look at my entry.

Comment: I thought "limes" is from Latin.

Comment: @Igor Belegradek: Why don't you take a look at this thread? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114190/schlicht-domain

Comment: Indeed, @GeraldEdgar, *limes* is good Latin, plural is *limites*.

Answer (score 4):

Einheit = word for unit in algebra. Hence, some use the notation $e\in G$ to denote the element of a group such that $ex = xe = x , \forall x \in G$. Unit is the appropriate translation, yet some algebraist still use the letter $e$ to denote the identity element in a group.

Comment: Well, sometimes it's also accidents of language that force this: e.g. "identity" is a good word to describe the unit, but the letter *i* was not really available any more, was it?

Comment: yes, i agree it is easy to use up the alphabet, but in this case, some people actually would use i to denote identity, cf. http://jeff560.tripod.com/i.html [scroll down to identity]

All the people I have read in the olden days, would write things like $\sqrt{-4} = 2\sqrt{-1}$ instead of $\sqrt{-4} = 2i$. I do not know of the first use of the symbol $i$ as a solution to $x^2 -1 =0$. 

Comment: According to Cajori, $i$ was first used by Euler in 1777 in a memoir which was not printer until 1794, after his death. It apparently did not appear anywhere else until 1801, when Gauss started to use it systematically.

Answer (score 4):

**Spiegelungssatz**. The meaning of this theorem is briefly
discussed in the article:  *Iwasawa theory and $p$-adic
deformations of motives* [MR1265554 (95i:11053)] by Ralph
Greenberg.

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and
$K_\infty=\mathbf{Q}(\mu_{p^\infty})$. Let $L_\infty$ denote the
maximal unramified abelian pro-$p$ extension of $K_\infty$, and
$M_\infty$ the maximal abelian pro-$p$-extension of $K_\infty$
that is unramified outside the primes above $p$. Let
$Y_\infty={\rm Gal}(L_\infty/K_\infty)$ and $X_\infty={\rm
Gal}(M_\infty/K_\infty)$. We can decompose ${\rm
Gal}(K_\infty/\mathbb{Q})\cong\Delta\times\Gamma$, where
$\Delta={\rm Gal}(\mathbf{Q}(\mu_p)/\mathbf{Q})$ and
$\Gamma\cong\mathbf{Z_p}$. Both $Y_\infty$ and $X_\infty$ have a
natural structure of $\Lambda$-modules
($\Lambda=\mathbf{Z_p}[[\Gamma]]$) coming from the action of ${\rm
Gal}(K_\infty/\mathbf{Q})$ by inner automorphisms. The latter
action gives in particular an action of $\Delta$, and hence we can
decompose $Y_\infty=\bigoplus_{i=0}^{p-2}Y_\infty^{\omega^i}$ and
$X_\infty=\bigoplus_{j=0}^{p-2}X_\infty^{\omega^j}$ as
$\Lambda$-modules, where the superscript denotes isotypical
component under the action of $\Delta$, and
$\omega:\Delta\rightarrow\mu_{p-1}$ denotes the mod $p$ cyclotomic
character. The spliegelungsatz is then described by Greenberg in
loc. cit. as an argument using Kummer theory and class field
theory that allows to relate the structures of
$X_\infty^{\omega^j}$ and $Y_\infty^{\omega^i}$ for $i+j\equiv
1\pmod{p-1}$ as $\Lambda$-modules.

Comment: +1.  You beat me to it by two hours.

Answer (score 4):

In topology the separation axioms  $T_0$ , $T_1$ .. etc, where the $T$ stands for Trennungsaxiom

Comment: I used to think that T stood for Tikhonov.

Comment: well, at least according to Munkres it stands for "Trennungsaxiom" (see page 211 Topology 2nd ed.) and wikipedia agrees, though whoever wrote the wikipedia article might have read it from munkres

Comment: I don't think that letters are really interesting ... 

Answer (score 3):

And what about the *Wiedersehen* metric?

Comment: Isn't it *auf Wiedershehen* metric, with *auf* and all?

Comment: Aw -- man, I was gonna respond with a comment just saying "Auf".

Answer (score 3):

The following theorem is known as Kugelsatz:

Let $X$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}^n, \quad n \geq 2$ and $K \subset X$ a compact subset such that $X\setminus K$ is connected. Then the restriction map $\rho: \mathcal{O}(X) \mapsto \mathcal{O}(X \setminus K)$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras (this version after: Volker Scheideman, *Introduction to Complex Analysis in Several Variables*, Birkhäuser 2005).

The first result of this kind is due to Hartogs, with $X$ and $K$ being concentric euclidean balls, hence the name (Kugel=ball). Many textbooks in several complex variables have been written by German-speaking authors (Grauert+Fritzsche, Kaup brothers are other examples), so the German name stuck even in the English version. The theorem is also referred to as "tomato can principle".

Answer (score 3):

One that is similar in spirit "eigenvalue" in that it mixes the two languages is 
$$
\text{umkehr map}
$$

Comment: Thanks John! I couldn't really believe this, but in fact there are even papers titled "Umkehr maps" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The Hegelian term *Aufhebung* has been appropriated by Lawvere to refer to relations between essential subtoposes of a cohesive topos, with a view to doing abstract homotopy theory. See the [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Aufhebung) for more.

Answer (score 2):

**Bew** (short for beweisbar, introduced by Gödel's incompleteness paper) is still used as a provability predicate in some mathematical logic papers.

In physics and other subjects (not so much in math) we hear about plenty of Gedankenexperiments.

Don't forget Hilbert's Satz 90, anomalous because of the "90" and not just the "Satz".

There are also French words like étale cohomology.

Comment: Maybe I'm a little slow today, but I don't find it as easy to come up with French mathematical terms. There is the unfortunately named *gerbe*, "étale" is a weird one because it looks like it somehow lost its last accent... Can't think of much more right now. I wonder if the concatenation property of German is what makes is so attractive for math, given that many example exhibit this feature.

Comment: Etale with only the first e marked is a French word. I have seen it on the package of a light bulb. 

Comment: A distinguished mathematician once referred to an assertion he was making in a conference talk as a "Theorem 90". He went on to explain that he was he was 50% sure of the proof--and that he had explained to a colleague, who was 40% sure.

Comment: @Thierry Zell, easy as child's play to find one more :) ... dessin d'enfant


Comment: @Tom: étale does exist; it's just obsolete in the common language, hence it's "weird" connotation. 

Comment: Also flasque, fppf, fpqc, idèle/adèle, répartition... 

Comment: And along with gerbes, there are also liens. Also, don't forget that $F_\sigma$ stands for "Ferm\'{e} somme" (while $G_\delta$ stands for Gebiet durchschnitt!). 

Comment: The two different words recouvrement and revêtement both roughly translate to covering, but as far as I can tell, the first is used to refer to open covers while the second to covering spaces. I think this is a wise decision and perhaps one we as English speakers can somehow adopt/adapt for our language.

Answer (score 2):

There is **Ahlfor's scheibensatz** in complex function theory, which is a generalization of  [Ahlfors five islands theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AhlforsFiveIslandTheorem.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you think of the symbols, you can also see Gothic, alternatively called German, letters.
Also, in algebraic topology, it is common to show the cycles by $Z$, which is the first letter of Zykel.

Also, many words that are Latin or Greek, in terms of the ingredients, were first coined and used in German, like Topologie which used to be called Analyse Situs.

It was common to show curvature by $K$, which stands for Krummung. Also, it was common to show a domain by B, for Bereiche. Or in riemannian geometry, the metric tensor is represented by $g$, which stands for Gravit\"at
Also, Faltung used to be common in English before the word convolution took over.

I can also add Umlaufssatz in the differential geometry of surfaces.

There are so many more...

Comment: There is also the inverse tendency that the German terms tend to be forgotten, now that English has become so prevalent. Many German students will happily use "Konvolution" when they read it in a paper before I teach them to use "Faltung". Similarly, "bottleneck" like in "bottleneck objective function" tends to be sometimes literally translated into "Flaschenhals" instead of "Engpass" (meaning narrow pass, which is (or used to be) the usual term in this situation). A case which I particularly deplore is the thoughtless translation of "line segment" into "Liniensegment" instead of "Strecke".

Comment: Gothic is ambiguous (as a term describing a typeface); Fraktur is probably what you meant, although it is a special case of blackletter (as opposed to whiteletter) fonts.

Answer (score 2):

There's a kind of combinatorial design called a *gerechte* design - essentially it's a Latin square with additional block constraints.  (I gather there's been a fad in recent years for newspapers to print partial gerechte designs of a certain kind for readers to complete.)  As a technical term, the word comes from the following paper:

W. U. Behrens (1956). Feldversuchsanordnungen mit verbessertem Ausgleich der Bodenunterschiede. Zeitschrift für Landwirtschaftliches Versuchs- und Untersuchungswesen, 2, 176–193.

Behrens' gerechte designs were 'fair' in how they apportioned plots of land to different treatments in an agricultural trial.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the Quermassintegral (mixed volumes of the form $V(K,K,\ldots,B,B)$ where $B$ is the unit ball, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_volume)), which I'm not even sure is German (not a lot of Qs in German usually).

Comment: Yes, German has Q's, and pronounces "qu" as "kv" as in "kvetch" (which indeed is from German "quetschen").

Answer (score 2):

[Schubfachprinzip](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1270/alternatives-to-pi-day/1273#1273) ("drawer principle" or "shelf principle" or  "Dirichlet's box principle"). It is now easy to guess we are talking about [P-H](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1270/alternatives-to-pi-day/1273#1273) [P](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4279/interesting-applications-of-the-pigeon-hole-principle).

Answer (score 1):

Ganzstellensatz.

Answer (score 1):

*Zusammenstellung*. Means "compilation" or "survey". Can be used in the first section of a paper, as one starts compiling "preliminary facts" to refer to later in the paper. That's the way I've seen it used in a paper by Raoul Bott.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Albrecht Frölich uses the german term *beweis*, instead of the english *proof*, in his chapter of the classic "Algebraic number theory". (EDIT: In my original version, I translated beweis to example. I shouldn't trust my poor knowledge of German... )

Comment: And to think, the number of times we tell students 'an example is not a proof'...

Answer (score 0):

In "Functional Analysis" by Kosaku Yosida he denotes the closure of a set $M$ by $M^a$.
He explains that it is a shortcut from German abgeschlossene Hulle.

Answer (score 0):

"schlichtartig" refers to a surface on which every simple closed curve which separates locally, also separates globally.  Hence it means roughly "planar".  This is used in the conformal mapping theory of Riemann surfaces.  Introduction to Riemann Surfaces, Springer, p. 91.  I know only a little German but it seems to translate something like "simply behaved"?

Answer (score 0):

Anzahl-theorems is  one I have recently read  in Wan's book on classical groups.

Answer (score 0):

**Gleichverteilungssatz**, which refers to both H. Weyl's result in complex analysis and ergodic theory ([1] §5, pp.18-19) and to several theorems in statistical physics
(Boltzmann's,... etc.).

[1] Heins, Maurice (1962), *Selected Topics in the Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable*, New York: Holt, Rinehart and Winston, Athena Series. Selected Topics in Mathematics, xi+160, [MR0162913](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0162913), [Zbl 1226.30001](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1226.30001).

Answer (score 0):

Kegelspitzen. There are directed complete orders equipped with a convex structure such that all relevant operations are (Scott) continuous. Introduced by Klaus Keimel and Gordon Plotkin in https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01005
It literally means "tip of a cone"; the motivation is that you would obtain a Kegelspitze by considering a cone and cutting of its tip. I guess that because the English description would be three words instead of a single one, the authors chose for the German translation, probably also because one of the authors was German.

Answer (score -1):

It's early in the morning, so maybe I missed it in the answers above, but, if we're including symbols, then the obvious example is $\mathbb{Z}$, the integers, or zahlen!

Ooops!  It is early in the morning... I see that Roland noted that the symbol for the integers (which I also can't seem to get to process properly) just a few comments above.

Answer (score -1):

In Swedish, a field is called a 'kropp', a body. This of course from the German word Körper.

Comment: That's is really stretching things; isn't it just as likely from the French "corps"?

Comment: Fields (in this algebraic sense) are called bodies in most languages. 

Comment: Some early English papers use the term "corpus" for field.

Answer (score -5):

The $\int$ symbol is a german S introduced by Leibniz and stands for Summe (Sum)

Comment: There is nothing German about the glyph $\int$ for the letter S.  It can be found in almost all French and English books of the time.

Comment: Even because Leibnitz wrote in Latin.

Comment: Several aspects of the typography stand out to modern eyes. Most noticeable of these is the use of the 'long s', visually resembling (but not pronounced as) a modern 'f' (as in the word 'Goſpel'). The modern form of the letter 's' was only used at the end of words, and in a few other specific circumstances. The 'long s' persisted in English print until the late 1700s, and survives in mathematics today as the symbol to denote an integral ('s' to denote a sum of infinitesimals).$$ $$  http://www.bl.uk/onlinegallery/sacredtexts/kingjames.html

$$ $$