# Schlicht domain

Tags: cv.complex-variables

What is a *schlicht* domain over $\mathbb{C}^n$? How is it different from a domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$? Examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Schlicht domain* over ${\mathbb C}^n$ is the same as a domain in ${\mathbb C}^n$. The point is that one also defines *domains over ${\mathbb C}^n$* as connected complex manifolds $M^n$ equipped with a locally biholomorphic map $f:M^n\to {\mathbb C}^n$. The *schlicht* property just means that $f$ is 1-1.

See http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Riemannian_domain for general definition and references for Riemann domains. People also consider *branched* Riemann domains where "locally biholomorphic" is replaced with "holomorphic with discrete fibers." These are  generalizations of Riemann surfaces of multivalued holomorphic functions of one variable.

Comment: More on the "schlicht property": http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62218/german-mathematical-terms-like-nullstellensatz/92721#92721


Comment: So, every domain in $\mathbb C^n$ is schlicht.